# Android: Refactor many groups of radio buttons in one activity

Tags: android, radio-button, kotlin

I want to create many radio groups in one activity like this

[image]

Following to Android docs, https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html, to make data binding to `Activity` to obtain value like "object1 = true, object2 = false". I've create 2 functions to get data from 2 radio groups.

In xml file, the code is

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Object 1."
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/pass_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked1"
        android:text="pass" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/not_pass_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked1"
        android:text="not pass" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/not_available_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked1"
        android:text="not available" />

</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Object 2."
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/pass_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked1"
        android:text="pass" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/not_pass_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked1"
        android:text="not pass" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/not_available_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked1"
        android:text="not available" />

</RadioGroup>
```

, and I create 2 functions like these:

```
fun onRadioButtonClicked1(view: View): Boolean? {
    val checked = (view as RadioButton).isChecked
    var value: Boolean? = null

    when (view.id) {
        R.id.pass_1 -> if (checked) value = true
        R.id.not_pass_1 -> if (checked) value = false
        R.id.not_available_1 -> if (checked) value = null
    }
    return value
}

fun onRadioButtonClicked2(view: View): Boolean? {
    val checked = (view as RadioButton).isChecked
    var value: Boolean? = null

    when (view.id) {
        R.id.pass_2 -> if (checked) value = true
        R.id.not_pass_2 -> if (checked) value = false
        R.id.not_available_2 -> if (checked) value = null
    }
    return value
}
```

Could it has some logic to refactor these stuff (like reuse this function)?

Answer (score 0):

Call the same function in all `onClick`s

`android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"`

Then add all 6 `case`s into the `when` statement

```
fun onRadioButtonClicked(view: View): Boolean? {
val checked = (view as RadioButton).isChecked
var value: Boolean? = null

when (view.id) {
    R.id.pass_1 -> if (checked) value = true
    R.id.not_pass_1 -> if (checked) value = false
    R.id.not_available_1 -> if (checked) value = null
    R.id.pass_2 -> if (checked) value = true
    R.id.not_pass_2 -> if (checked) value = false
    R.id.not_available_2 -> if (checked) value = null
}
return value
```

}

Comment: hmm.., I think this code return only 1 value. I need 2 values, 1 value in each topic.

Comment: Im sorry but i only see onClick method binding in your code, where is the data binding part?

Comment: I've do like `value1 = onRadioButtonClicked1(view)` and `value2 = onRadioButtonClicked2()`

Answer (score 0):

First evident method:

```
var value1: Boolean? = null
var value2: Boolean? = null

fun onRadioButtonClicked(view: View) {
    val checked = (view as RadioButton).isChecked

    when (view.id) {
        R.id.pass_1 -> if (checked) value1 = true
        R.id.not_pass_1 -> if (checked) value1 = false
        R.id.not_available_1 -> if (checked) value1 = null
        R.id.pass_2 -> if (checked) value2 = true
        R.id.not_pass_2 -> if (checked) value2 = false
        R.id.not_available_2 -> if (checked) value2 = null
    }
}
```

But if you have plenty of RadioGroup, an alternative is to set Tag on XML for each RadioButton (I used for the example below string "TRUE", "FALSE"):

```
var value1: Boolean? = null
var value2: Boolean? = null

fun onRadioButtonClicked1(view: View) = onRadioButtonClicked(view) { value1 = it }
fun onRadioButtonClicked2(view: View) = onRadioButtonClicked(view) { value2 = it }

fun onRadioButtonClicked(view: View, function: (Boolean?) -> Unit) {
    val checked = (view as RadioButton).isChecked

    if (checked) {
        view.tag
                .let {
                    when (it) {
                        "TRUE" -> true
                        "FALSE" -> false
                        else -> null
                    }
                }
                .let { function.invoke(it) }
    }
}
```

I didn't check, but I think you have more appropriate callback, something like onCheckedChanged on RadioButton or RadioGroup.